# The sum of all even numbers between 2 and 100 in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

```
%include "asm_io.inc"
;
; initialized data is put in the .data segment
;
segment .data


; uninitialized data is put in the .bss segment
;
segment .bss

;
; code is put in the .text segment
;
segment .text
        global  asm_main
asm_main:
        enter   0,0               ; setup routine
        pusha
; put your code below this comment.
        mov eax,2
        mov ecx,100

loop_start: add eax,ecx
            loop loop_start

loop_end: call print_int
          call print_nl


; don't delete anything following this comment
        popa
        mov     eax, 0            ; return back to C
        leave
        ret
```

Please understand that I'm a beginner haha. I know how to find the sum of all numbers between 2 and 100 but I'm not sure how to add just the even numbers between 2 and 100. The answer should be 2550, but I get the answer that sums up all the numbers.

Comment: If you want only the even numbers, you'll want to count down by 2 to skip odd numbers, not just 1 like `loop` does.  e.g. use `sub ecx,2` / `ja`

Comment: Do I have to make another loop and use sub ecx, 2 or ja? And just out of curiosity, what function would I have to use if I'm doing the opposite, meaning adding only odd numbers?

Comment: No, use those 2 instructions *instead* of the `loop` instruction as the bottom of your existing loop.  The `loop` instruction isn't the only way to write loops.  (I meant `ja loop_start`, of course, instead of `loop loop_start`)

Comment: Thank you. Last question, what other instruction would I have to use if it's the sum of odd numbers only?

Comment: The same loop, from a different starting point.  Think about what exactly `sub ecx, 2` / `ja` does, and the `do{}while()` loop it corresponds to.